Grid layout jumping around
I have a Grid that is set up into 12x12 elements, using 12 rows and 12 columns, each row/column using a Width/Height of "*" so everything is evenly spaced.
I then have controls that I put into this grid with their location set using Grid.Row and Grid.Column.
The content of each of these controls can be Visible or Collapsed depending on logic within the view model.
What I am finding is that that if I have UseLayoutRounding set to false, all is good. But if I have it set to true, each "cell" of the 12x12 grid will change size depending on whether the content is visible or not.
For example, if the Grid is say 1200x1200px, then each cell of the grid is about 100x100px. If the cell content is Visible then its 100px, but sometimes, if the cell content is not visible its 99x or 101px? depending on snapping due to UseLayoutRounding
Whilst this might seem a small change, its really obvious as it seems to propagate throughout all the cells, such that each cell will move along by 1 pixel when some other cells content is collapsed or made visible.
I cannot disable layout rounding as I need it to prevent other issues related to blurry lines.
Is there a way to fix this grid issue? I don't mind if some cells are 99px or 101px, I just don't want it to keep changing based on their content (assuming the grid itself is not being resized).

Try Hidden instead of Collapsed, so that elements still participate in layout. Also try using a UniformGrid instead of a Grid.

Thank you for the suggestions. Hidden helps, but I'd rather avoid that solution as there is a large hierarchy inside each cell, with multiple bindings for visibility at multiple levels, so it would mean changing unrelated datatemplates defined in a different part of the code base :( . As for UniformGrid, I don't think that will work with bindings for row/column index will it? Each item has a specific location its wants to be in, as well as some items specifying a span to span more than one row/column.

If I was to write my own panel that calls child.Arrange in ArrangeOverride and then also sets the child Width and Height to fixed values, so that they remain the same size irrespective of their desired size, would that be a terrible idea?

Not at all a terrible idea. Give it a try.

Don't you use a converter  to toggle the visibility? In this case you would only have to modify the converter. Instead of implementing a custom Panel you could also try to use a converter to calculate the cell dimensions. Having a fixed cell dimensions should eliminate the behavior.

@BionicCode the visibility of the content is defined at multiple levels in the hierarchy, so not a small change really. I did however implement the custom panel (100 lines of code) and it seems to have solved the problem, I didn't even need to add the code for setting the fixed width and height.

Maybe SnapsToDevicePixels = true at the grid level fix the issue.

This seemed to do the trick for me. As mentioned in my comment above, I didn't need to add the code for setting a fixed width and height on the child in the ArrangeOverride, but that is still an option.
public class FixedGrid : Panel
{
    public int Cells
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(CellsProperty);
        set => SetValue(CellsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CellsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Cells), typeof(int), typeof(FixedGrid), new PropertyMetadata(12));

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double cellWidth = availableSize.Width / Cells;
        double cellHeight = availableSize.Height / Cells;

        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            int rowSpan = Grid.GetRowSpan(child);
            int colSpan = Grid.GetColumnSpan(child);

            double width = colSpan * cellWidth;
            double height = rowSpan * cellHeight;

            child.Measure(new Size(width, height));
        }

        return availableSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double cellWidth = finalSize.Width / Cells;
        double cellHeight = finalSize.Height / Cells;

        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            int row = Grid.GetRow(child);
            int col = Grid.GetColumn(child);
            int rowSpan = Grid.GetRowSpan(child);
            int colSpan = Grid.GetColumnSpan(child);

            double width = colSpan * cellWidth;
            double height = rowSpan * cellHeight;

            child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(col * cellWidth, row * cellHeight), new Size(width, height)));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}


Because you can't change the way the cell content is hidden you can assign fixed cell dimensions. This should eliminate the rendering issues. This could also be more efficient than setting cell content to  Visibility.Hidden instead of Visibility.Collapsed.
A small attached behavior that dynamically calculates the cells could look as follows:
Usage example
<Grid GridService.ColumnCount="12" 
      GridService.RowCount="12">
  <Button Grid.Row="0"
          Content="Button" />
  <Button Grid.Row="1"
          Content="Button" />
  <Button Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="3"
          Content="Button" />
</Grid>

GridService.cs
public class GridService : DependencyObject
{
  public static int GetRowCount(DependencyObject attachingElement) 
    => (int)attachingElement.GetValue(RowCountProperty);

  public static void SetRowCount(DependencyObject attachingElement, int value) 
    => attachingElement.SetValue(RowCountProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty RowCountProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "RowCount", 
    typeof(int), 
    typeof(GridService), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnCellCountChanged));

  public static int GetColumnCount(DependencyObject attachingElement) 
    => (int)attachingElement.GetValue(ColumnCountProperty);

  public static void SetColumnCount(DependencyObject attachingElement, int value)
    => attachingElement.SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnCountProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ColumnCount",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(GridService), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnCellCountChanged));

  private static void OnCellCountChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
  {
    if (attachingElement is not Grid grid)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException($"Attaching element must be of type {typeof(Grid).FullName}", nameof(attachingElement));
    }

    WeakEventManager<Grid, SizeChangedEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(grid, nameof(FrameworkElement.SizeChanged), OnGridResized);
    WeakEventManager<Grid, SizeChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(grid, nameof(FrameworkElement.SizeChanged), OnGridResized);

    LayoutGridCells(grid);
  }

  private static void OnGridResized(object? sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    => LayoutGridCells((Grid)sender);

  private static void LayoutGridCells(Grid grid)
  {
    ArrangeColumns(grid);
    ArrangeRows(grid);      
  }

  private static void ArrangeColumns(Grid grid)
  {
    int newColumnCount = GetColumnCount(grid);
    int currentColumnCount = grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
    int changedColumnCount = Math.Abs(newColumnCount - currentColumnCount);
    if (currentColumnCount > newColumnCount)
    {
      grid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveRange(currentColumnCount - changedColumnCount, changedColumnCount);
    }
    else if (currentColumnCount < newColumnCount)
    {
      for (int count = 0; count < changedColumnCount; count++)
      {
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
      }
    }

    double cellWidth = grid.ActualWidth / newColumnCount;
    foreach (ColumnDefinition column in grid.ColumnDefinitions)
    {
      column.Width = new GridLength(cellWidth, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    }
  }

  private static void ArrangeRows(Grid grid)
  {
    int newRowCount = GetRowCount(grid);
    int currentRowCount = grid.RowDefinitions.Count;
    int changedRowCount = Math.Abs(newRowCount - currentRowCount);
    if (currentRowCount > newRowCount)
    {
      grid.RowDefinitions.RemoveRange(currentRowCount - changedRowCount, changedRowCount);
    }
    else if (currentRowCount < newRowCount)
    {
      for (int count = 0; count < changedRowCount; count++)
      {
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
      }
    }

    double cellHeight = grid.ActualHeight / newRowCount;
    foreach (RowDefinition row in grid.RowDefinitions)
    {
      row.Height = new GridLength(cellHeight, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    }
  }
}


Thanks for this, I'll see how the custom panel goes first as it fits in a little nicer within the code base.
